# Which method is preferred when prototyping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here's a contrived example:

I want to divide two numbers and I need to write a method for doing so. I could write something like this:

```
function divide(dividend,divisor) {
    return dividend/divisor;
};

//Assign the result of the divide function to an element on the page.
$(".firstanswer").html(divide(6,2));
```

I could also write something like this:

```
Number.prototype.dividedBy = function (divisor)​ {
    var dividend = this;
    return dividend/divisor;
};

var six = 6;
var two = 2;
$(".secondanswer").html(six.dividedBy(two));
```

Both methods yield the same answer, so what I'd like to know is this:
What are the advantages or disadvantages to using either method. Is there a significant performance (load/run time) difference? Is one more *reusable* than the other in terms of memory impact? What about ease of comprehension? Ultimately, for an example as simplistic as this, does it matter?

I've also [created a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeCkQ/) because code is better.

Comment: IMO, the first is more practical for callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no disadvantage in first method (except for different syntax)

In second method, you risk the implementation, what if it becomes part of `Number` or `Math` object or some other third party library having same function name :)

Though normally to avoid it, this is done:

```
Number.prototype.dividedBy = Number.prototype.dividedBy || function (divisor)​ {
    var dividend = this;
    return dividend/divisor;
};
```

This way, you say, if there is that function already present use that else create my own.

---

For more details, check out (yet another great article by [@Kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) as always)

- [Extending built-in native objects. Evil or not?](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/)

Comment: This is perfect, and your supplied code is very useful. Thanks for your answer.